# Download project via Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

All I want is the project file/jar for this project: http://thiagolocatelli.github.io/parse4j/

It says I need to do the following to obtain it:

```
Getting Started
Download the library manually
Maven
<project ...>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.thiagolocatelli</groupId>
            <artifactId>parse4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

I have never used Maven, do not really know what it is. Can someone advice me how I obtain the project file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get started with maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126090/get-started-with-maven)

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a dependency manager. Lots of information about it if you're interested - just use your favorite search engine.

You can also download the jar file directly from http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/thiagolocatelli/parse4j/1.3/parse4j-1.3.jar

Comment: Thanks mate, but when I add the jar to my buildpath I get a bunch of error when running my project like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: How do I find and link all the dependencies?

Comment: That's what maven is for.

Comment: So how do I add the dependencies with Maven?

Comment: @LukeTaylor Adding the dependency into the Maven POM file should automatically add the necessary files to your build path... So I need to ask if you're using Maven to build your code? There is a Maven plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Do I have to convert my project to a Maven project?

Comment: I have converted my project to a Maven Project and added the dependency to Maven POM file, yet it spits out a bunch of error when building... Why do they have to make it so complicated

Comment: I get a NoGoalSpecifiedException

Comment: Now I get Error: Could not find or load main class SplashyFish.GameBase.Game